# Calculating standard deviation when some dates are missing

Tags: sql

I have the input data:
I want to calculate the standard deviation such that the missing dates values of item_demand should be taken as 0.

Input Data:

```
+---+---------------+-------------+
|   | checkout_date | item_demand |
+---+---------------+-------------+
| 0 | 2022-08-02    |           1 |
| 1 | 2022-08-05    |           2 |
| 2 | 2022-08-07    |           1 |
| 3 | 2022-08-08    |           1 |
| 4 | 2022-08-09    |           1 |
| 5 | 2022-08-12    |           2 |
+---+---------------+-------------+
```

I used inbuilt function :

```
cast(stddev(item_demand) as dec(14,2)) deviation
```

But since some of my dates are missing the inbuilt function won't give a proper result; I want to take into account the missing dates (with item_demand as 0 ) also, and then I want the standard deviation.
Please suggest how to achieve this. I'm new to SQL

Comment: mysql or postgres? even so use a time series to get the missing dates and use then the function

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: If you add a where clause on date in your select query? I mean, where checkout_date IS NOT NULL? I think another way is to use the CASE statement